# WKWebView turns black when "Open Link" pressed after long press a link

Tags: swift, webview, wkwebview

I'm programming in swift and run into an error that my WKWebView turns black after "open link" or "add to photos" in safari.

So I got my WebView and everything works fine. But when I long press on (e.g. an image) the apple-dropdown-menu opens with "open link", "add to reading list", ..., "add to photos". Now when I just close the dropdown menu again and go to home screen and open the app again, the webview turns black. The console says it's loading and didFinish, but I can't see anything. Anyone knows possible issues?

When I pressed "open link" on the dropdown-menu safari opens with that link. But when I move back to my app, the screen turns black. Here is the code of the console after opening my app again.

```
--------------------- SCENEDELEGATE sceneWillEnterForeground ---------------------

2020-08-13 13:48:38.560642+0200 GMP[1817:418564] [ProcessSuspension] 0x282f2aa00 - WKProcessAssertionBackgroundTaskManager: Ignored request to start a new background task because the application is already in the background
2020-08-13 13:48:38.561286+0200 GMP[1817:418564] [ProcessSuspension] 0x282f2aa00 - WKProcessAssertionBackgroundTaskManager: Ignored request to start a new background task because the application is already in the background
--------------------- SCENEDELEGATE sceneDidBecomeActive ---------------------
currentUrl: https://myWebPage.com/
loadUrl(link: https://myWebPage.com/)
didStartProvisionalNavigation webView(_:didStartProvisionalNavigation:)
didCommit webView(_:didCommit:)
2020-08-13 13:48:39.341814+0200 GMP[1817:418614] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x282ff4db0; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Client is missing required entitlement"> {
    userInfo = {
        RBSAssertionAttribute = <RBSLegacyAttribute: 0x102c8f640; requestedReason: FinishTaskUnbounded; reason: FinishTaskUnbounded; flags: PreventTaskSuspend>;
    }
}
2020-08-13 13:48:39.341902+0200 GMP[1817:418614] [ProcessSuspension]  0x1094e0438 - ProcessAssertion() PID 1817 Unable to acquire assertion for process with PID 1819
2020-08-13 13:48:39.342137+0200 GMP[1817:418564] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1094e0438 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-08-13 13:48:39.342917+0200 GMP[1817:418614] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x282ff4de0; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Client is missing required entitlement"> {
    userInfo = {
        RBSAssertionAttribute = <RBSLegacyAttribute: 0x1040ae040; requestedReason: FinishTaskUnbounded; reason: FinishTaskUnbounded; flags: PreventTaskSuspend>;
    }
}
2020-08-13 13:48:39.342998+0200 GMP[1817:418614] [ProcessSuspension]  0x1094e0460 - ProcessAssertion() PID 1817 Unable to acquire assertion for process with PID 1817
2020-08-13 13:48:39.343085+0200 GMP[1817:418564] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1094e0460 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-08-13 13:48:39.343851+0200 GMP[1817:418614] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x282ffcea0; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Client is missing required entitlement"> {
    userInfo = {
        RBSAssertionAttribute = <RBSLegacyAttribute: 0x10415ddb0; requestedReason: FinishTaskUnbounded; reason: FinishTaskUnbounded; flags: PreventTaskSuspend>;
    }
}
2020-08-13 13:48:39.343954+0200 GMP[1817:418614] [ProcessSuspension]  0x1094e0488 - ProcessAssertion() PID 1817 Unable to acquire assertion for process with PID 1818
2020-08-13 13:48:39.344028+0200 GMP[1817:418564] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1094e0488 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-08-13 13:48:39.905526+0200 GMP[1817:418815] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x282f3b690; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Client is missing required entitlement"> {
    userInfo = {
        RBSAssertionAttribute = <RBSLegacyAttribute: 0x10414ea00; requestedReason: FinishTaskUnbounded; reason: FinishTaskUnbounded; flags: PreventTaskSuspend>;
    }
}
2020-08-13 13:48:39.905574+0200 GMP[1817:418815] [ProcessSuspension]  0x1094e20a8 - ProcessAssertion() PID 1817 Unable to acquire assertion for process with PID 1819
2020-08-13 13:48:39.905602+0200 GMP[1817:418564] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1094e20a8 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-08-13 13:48:39.906163+0200 GMP[1817:418815] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x282f39590; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Client is missing required entitlement"> {
    userInfo = {
        RBSAssertionAttribute = <RBSLegacyAttribute: 0x102d4d0c0; requestedReason: FinishTaskUnbounded; reason: FinishTaskUnbounded; flags: PreventTaskSuspend>;
    }
}
2020-08-13 13:48:39.906196+0200 GMP[1817:418815] [ProcessSuspension]  0x1094e20d0 - ProcessAssertion() PID 1817 Unable to acquire assertion for process with PID 1817
2020-08-13 13:48:39.906218+0200 GMP[1817:418564] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1094e20d0 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
2020-08-13 13:48:39.906769+0200 GMP[1817:418815] [assertion] Error acquiring assertion: <NSError: 0x282f391d0; domain: RBSAssertionErrorDomain; code: 2; reason: "Client is missing required entitlement"> {
    userInfo = {
        RBSAssertionAttribute = <RBSLegacyAttribute: 0x102c66420; requestedReason: FinishTaskUnbounded; reason: FinishTaskUnbounded; flags: PreventTaskSuspend>;
    }
}
2020-08-13 13:48:39.906803+0200 GMP[1817:418815] [ProcessSuspension]  0x1094e20f8 - ProcessAssertion() PID 1817 Unable to acquire assertion for process with PID 1818
2020-08-13 13:48:39.906828+0200 GMP[1817:418564] [ProcessSuspension] 0x1094e20f8 - ProcessAssertion::processAssertionWasInvalidated()
didFinish webView(_:didFinish:)
didSet currentUrl = https://myWebPage.com/
```

Comment: running on simulator? try it in device.. check this https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/127734

Comment: Running on my iPhone 11. But the app is not published yet. I've read that the error with the transparent statusbar should be gone when it's in appStore. But I think here is another problem.. Thanks for the link but it doesn't help..